# Animate button on UITableViewCell without affecting other UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell with the following code where a user clicks on the "Save" button on a UITableViewCell. The image in the cell is saved, and the "Save" button is animated away, but the cell remains.

```
   -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  if (!self.tableCell)
    {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"LPContentTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ContentCell"];

        self.tableCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ContentCell"];
    }

        [self.tableCell.saveImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        return self.tableCell;

    }

    -(void)saveImage:(id)sender{

     UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

    //image is saved

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
            button.frame = newFrame;
        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                [button removeFromSuperview];


    }];
```

Problem is, the cells not allocated at the time I press save also lose their save buttons. I casted the button as the sender. The button is removed and the buttons on the next few cells remain. However, cells further down in the UITableView appear when I scroll without the button. Ideas?

EDIT: suggestions incorporated

```
UIButton * cellButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[cellButton setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cellButton.frame = CGRectMake(268, 95, 79, 23);
[self.tableCell.contentView addSubview:cellButton];


-(void)saveImage:(id)sender{
UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;


CGRect newFrame = button.frame;

newFrame.origin.x +=100;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
   button.frame = newFrame;

}completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [button removeFromSuperview];

}];
```

Comment: Where is the cell alloc or deque cell with identifier method

Comment: in cellForRow. Originally omitted for brevity. Added above.

Comment: Create button for every cell and add a tag and check correspondingly.

Comment: UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; this need to come that place instead of your        [self.tableCell.saveImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 or else go for custom cell and use delegate to call the button

Comment: But what comes after this? I know the row, but since now it's not a property I can't do [cell.view removeFromSuperview]; It animates, but never gets removed.

Comment: Why are you using a property for the cell?
Do you need self.tableCell for something else?

Comment: @KrisJurgowski made a custom cell xib. Nope, not for anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are breaking the MVC pattern with your implementation.

cellForIndexPath gets called whenever a cell is about to be presented on screen and should avoid needed to remember anything about your model (the images). Use indexPaths to get access to your model in methods.

The proper way to implement this is separate that out.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Register you nib here. You only need to do this once.
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"LPContentTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ContentCell"];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Dequeuing will create or reuse cell. This is what that iOS silky smooth scrollin is all about
    LPContentTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ContentCell" forIndexPath: indexPath];

    BOOL canSave = YES; //figure out if image at indexPath can be saved..

    NSArray *targets = [cell.saveImageButton actionsForTarget:self forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    if ([targets count] == 0) {
        // Only add the target once per cell.. it would be easier to just add the target in IB instead of this method.
        [cell.saveImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }


    if (canSave) {
        cell.saveImageButton.alpha = 1;
    }
    else {
        cell.saveImageButton.alpha = 0;
    }
}

-(void)saveImage:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    LPContentTableViewCell *cell = [button superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    // Get image using indexPath and Save

    CGRect newFrame = button.frame;
    newFrame.origin.x +=100;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
       button.frame = newFrame;

    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        // Use alpha instead of removing the view so reused cells can just set the alpha back to 1
        button.alpha = 0;

        // Set the old frame back here too for reused cells.
        button.frame = oldFrame;
    }];
}
```

You LPContentTableViewCell's interface should look something like this.

```
@interface LPContentTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *saveImageButton;  // This needs to be connected with IB

@end
```

Comment: Seems to be in issue with cell registration or reuse, so I had to do if (!cell) cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ContentCell"]; Cell alloc's but it's properties aren't there anymore

Comment: My mistake, the other dequeue method always returns a valid cell. I will update.

Comment: It works but I had to add subviews to the cell programmatically because the properties of the cell logged as null. Seems to be something a bit off that I can't figure out. Can you update to see how your implementation works?

Comment: You need to connect your buttons in Interface Builder to IBOutlets in the code.

Open Xcode in assistant view and connect the button to `saveImageButton` which should be an IBOutlet.

Comment: They are outlets, but it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Still, properties don't work. I just added the view elements programmatically as subviews to cell.contentView and it works. By doing so in saveImage method [button superview] should be [[button superview] superview]. I appreciate the help.

Comment: You can hold control and drag a view in Interface Builder into the property in code to connect it.

Comment: Now the problem with this code is that the button reappears when I scroll past the cell and scroll back to it. It seems like it should be easier than this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to programmatically  create a new button for every cell.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
        action:@selector(aMethod:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`
```

And you can add a tag to it as some type of identifier.

`[button setTag:rowNumber];`

Comment: So, in cellForRow create the button. Then in saveImage set the tag? Do I still need to cast UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;?

Comment: Set the tag of the button in cellForRow. Then in the method that is called when the button is clicked access that tag and use it to get the cell with [tableView indexPathForCell:[(UIButton *)sender tag]];

Comment: Still don't get it. That method takes as parameter a cell and returns an indexPath which I already have as it's the tag of the button.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  if (!self.tableCell)
    {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"LPContentTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ContentCell"];

        self.tableCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ContentCell"];
    }

           UIButton * cellButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
          [cellButton setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          [cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
          cellButton.frame = CGRectMake(127, 8, 50, 30);
          [cell.contentView addSubview:cellButton];

        return self.tableCell;

    }

    -(void)saveImage:(UIButton*)sender{

    //image is saved

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{

        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                [sender removeFromSuperview];


    }];
```

Comment: how to identify which cell is called

Comment: works but for the sender.frame - i get red. I think another button gets alloc'd as a button is animated and removed but the original "Save" cellButton sticks around for some reason. Thanks

Comment: now look at my code,have you added any buttons through storyboard or nib,if yes remove them,and my code is useful to you don't forget to accept the answer...:)

Comment: Tried but still doesn't work properly - a new button is created which is animated but the original button stays in it's place.

Comment: do you removed your saveImageButton,are you sure..?

Comment: I removed the saveImageButton but when I run and click on the button, a "save" button animates they way I want BUT the original "save" button is still there - I can't figure out why there are 2 "save" buttons.

Comment: see above. I kept sender as button as it seems to do the same thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63393/discussion-between-noobsmcgoobs-and-iraki).